# Writing a Domain Specific Language for selecting rows from a table

Tags: python, database, algorithm, dsl

I'm writing a server that I expect to be run by many different people, not all of whom I will have direct contact with. The servers will communicate with each other in a cluster. Part of the server's functionality involves selecting a small subset of rows from a potentially very large table. The exact choice of what rows are selected will need some tuning, and it's important that it's possible for the person running the cluster (eg, myself) to update the selection criteria without getting each and every server administrator to deploy a new version of the server.

Simply writing the function in Python isn't really an option, since nobody is going to want to install a server that downloads and executes arbitrary Python code at runtime.

What I need are suggestions on the simplest way to implement a Domain Specific Language to achieve this goal. The language needs to be capable of simple expression evaluation, as well as querying table indexes and iterating through the returned rows. Ease of writing and reading the language is secondary to ease of implementing it. I'd also prefer not to have to write an entire query optimiser, so something that explicitly specifies what indexes to query would be ideal.

The interface that this will have to compile against will be similar in capabilities to what the App Engine datastore exports: You can query for sequential ranges on any index on the table (eg, less-than, greater-than, range and equality queries), then filter the returned row by any boolean expression. You can also concatenate multiple independent result sets together.

I realise this question sounds a lot like I'm asking for SQL. However, I don't want to require that the datastore backing this data be a relational database, and I don't want the overhead of trying to reimplement SQL myself. I'm also dealing with only a single table with a known schema. Finally, no joins will be required. Something much simpler would be far preferable.

Edit: Expanded description to clear up some misconceptions.

Comment: Was this for implementing GQL in App Engine? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building a DSL to be interpreted by Python.

Step 1.  Build the run-time classes and objects.  These classes will have all the cursor loops and SQL statements and all of that algorithmic processing tucked away in their methods.  You'll make heavy use of the [Command](http://exciton.cs.rice.edu/javaresources/DesignPatterns/command.htm) and [Strategy](http://exciton.cs.rice.edu/javaresources/DesignPatterns/StrategyPattern.htm) design patterns to build these classes.  Most things are a command, options and choices are plug-in strategies.  Look at the design for Apache Ant's [Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) API -- it's a good example.

Step 2.  Validate that this system of objects actually works.  Be sure that the design is simple and complete.  You're tests will construct the Command and Strategy objects, and then execute the top-level Command object.  The Command objects will do the work.

At this point you're largely done.  Your run-time is just a configuration of objects created from the above domain.  [This isn't as easy as it sounds.  It requires some care to define a set of classes that can be instantiated and then "talk among themselves" to do the work of your application.]

Note that what you'll have will require nothing more than declarations.  What's wrong with procedural?  One you start to write a DSL with procedural elements, you find that you need more and more features until you've written Python with different syntax.  Not good.

Further, procedural language interpreters are simply hard to write.  State of execution, and scope of references are simply hard to manage.

You can use native Python -- and stop worrying about "getting out of the sandbox".  Indeed, that's how you'll unit test everything, using a short Python script to create your objects.  Python will be the DSL.

["But wait", you say, "If I simply use Python as the DSL people can execute arbitrary things."  Depends on what's on the PYTHONPATH, and sys.path.  Look at the [site](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-site.html) module for ways to control what's available.]

A declarative DSL is simplest.  It's entirely an exercise in representation.  A block of Python that merely sets the values of some variables is nice.  That's what Django uses.

You can use the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-ConfigParser.html) as a language for representing your run-time configuration of objects.

You can use [JSON](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-json/) or [YAML](http://pyyaml.org/) as a language for representing your run-time configuration of objects.  Ready-made parsers are totally available.

You can use XML, too.  It's harder to design and parse, but it works fine.  People love it.  That's how Ant and Maven (and lots of other tools) use declarative syntax to describe procedures.  I don't recommend it, because it's a wordy pain in the neck.  I recommend simply using Python.

Or, you can go off the deep-end and invent your own syntax and write your own parser.

Comment: All good suggestions, but I'm still looking for a suggestion of an effective syntax or format. Procedural or declarative? How best to handle cursors? Etc.

Comment: Edited to respond to these two points.  Declarative.  SQL Cursor Loops are in the core classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think we're going to need a bit more information here.  Let me know if any of the following is based on incorrect assumptions.

First of all, as you pointed out yourself, there already exists a DSL for selecting rows from arbitrary tables-- it is called "SQL".  Since you don't want to reinvent SQL, I'm assuming that you only need to query from a single table with a fixed format.

If this is the case, you probably don't need to implement a DSL (although that's certainly one way to go); it may be easier, if you are used to Object Orientation, to create a Filter object.

More specifically, a "Filter" collection that would hold one or more SelectionCriterion objects.  You can implement these to inherit from one or more base classes representing types of selections (Range, LessThan, ExactMatch, Like, etc.) Once these base classes are in place, you can create column-specific inherited versions which are appropriate to that column.  Finally, depending on the complexity of the queries you want to support, you'll want to implement some kind of connective glue to handle AND and OR and NOT linkages between the various criteria.

If you feel like it, you can create a simple GUI to load up the collection; I'd look at the filtering in Excel as a model, if you don't have anything else in mind.

Finally, it should be trivial to convert the contents of this Collection to the corresponding SQL, and pass that to the database.

However: if what you are after is simplicity, and your users understand SQL, you could simply ask them to type in the contents of a WHERE clause, and programmatically build up the rest of the query.  From a security perspective, if your code has control over the columns selected and the FROM clause, and your database permissions are set properly, and you do some sanity checking on the string coming in from the users, this would be a relatively safe option.

Comment: Mostly sound, but I still need some way to specify the filter collection etc. Bear in mind that the goal here is for me to be able to specify an updated function and have it propagate to all the servers in a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

"implement a Domain Specific Language"

"nobody is going to want to install a server that downloads and executes arbitrary Python code at runtime"

I want a DSL but I don't want Python to be that DSL.  Okay.  How will you execute this DSL?  What runtime *is* acceptable if not Python?

What if I have a C program that happens to embed the Python interpreter?  Is that acceptable?

And -- if Python is not an acceptable runtime -- why does this have a Python tag?

Comment: I'll execute the DSL by writing an interpreter in Python. That's why it has the Python tag. The whole point of using a DSL in this case is that it won't allow code written in it to break out of the sandbox and affect the system as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a language that when it "compiles" it generates SQL or whatever query language your datastore requires ?

You would be basically creating an abstraction over your persistence layer.

Comment: The server architecture allows for multiple possible datastore implementations. The simplest possible one is a simple in-memory table, so the query language my datastore requires is, well, Python.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Python. Why not use Python? If someone can "type in" an expression in your DSL, they can type in Python.

You'll need some rules on structure of the expression, but that's a lot easier than implementing something new.

Comment: I already said why: Nobody is going to want to run a server that downloads and executes arbitrary code at runtime. And a parser that can check Python thoroughly enough to ensure it's doing nothing malicious is likely to be nearly as complicated as writing a proper DSL anyway.

Comment: But that's a security issue that can be managed. For example, you DBA can download arbitrary code at runtime. Considering how rare this process seems to be, no reason it can't be done by someone trusted to do the work.

Comment: The whole point is that it can't require manual intervention from each server administrator. I need a DSL that's capable of querying/filtering in this fashion, but that server administrators can trust to be updated without their intervention or supervision.

Answer (score 0):

You said nobody is going to want to install a server that downloads and executes arbitrary code at runtime.  However, that is exactly what your DSL will do (eventually) so there probably isn't that much of a difference.  Unless you're doing something very specific with the data then I don't think a DSL will buy you that much and it will frustrate the users who are already versed in SQL.  Don't underestimate the size of the task you'll be taking on.

To answer your question however, you will need to come up with a grammar for your language, something to parse the text and walk the tree, emitting code or calling an API that you've written (which is why my comment that you're still going to have to ship some code).

There are plenty of educational texts on grammars for mathematical expressions you can refer to on the net, that's fairly straight forward.  You may have a parser generator tool like ANTLR or Yacc you can use to help you generate the parser (or use a language like Lisp/Scheme and marry the two up).  Coming up with a reasonable SQL grammar won't be easy.  But google 'BNF SQL' and see what you come up with.

Best of luck.

Comment: Yes, it'll download 'arbitrary' code, but when it's expressed in terms of this DSL, it can't do much. There's a world of difference between arbitrary Python code and an arbitrary filter expression (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like SQL, but perhaps it's worth to try using SQLite if you want to keep it simple?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a grammar not a DSL.  I'd look into [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) which will allow you to create a specific parser that will interpret text and translate to specific commands.  ANTLR provides libraries for Python, SQL, Java, C++, C, C# etc.

Also, here is a fine example of an ANTLR [calculation engine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sota_expression_evaluator.aspx) created in C#

Comment: It's more than just a grammar - I need to not just parse it, but to execute it, which makes it a complete DSL. The example of the 'calculation engine' just has the execution code embedded in the parser.

Answer (score 0):

A context-free grammar usually has a tree like structure and functional programs have a tree like structure too. I don't claim the following would solve all of your problems, but it is a good step in the direction if you are sure that you don't want to use something like `SQLite3`.

```
from functools import partial
def select_keys(keys, from_):
    return ({k : fun(v, row) for k, (v, fun) in keys.items()}
            for row in from_)

def select_where(from_, where):
    return (row for row in from_
            if where(row))

def default_keys_transform(keys, transform=lambda v, row: row[v]):
    return {k : (k, transform) for k in keys}

def select(keys=None, from_=None, where=None):
    """
    SELECT v1 AS k1, 2*v2 AS k2 FROM table WHERE v1 = a AND v2 >= b OR v3 = c

    translates to 

    select(dict(k1=(v1, lambda v1, r: r[v1]), k2=(v2, lambda v2, r: 2*r[v2])
        , from_=table
        , where= lambda r : r[v1] = a and r[v2] >= b or r[v3] = c)
    """
    assert from_ is not None
    idfunc = lambda k, t : t
    select_k = idfunc if keys is None  else select_keys
    if isinstance(keys, list):
        keys = default_keys_transform(keys)
    idfunc = lambda t, w : t
    select_w = idfunc if where is None else select_where
    return select_k(keys, select_w(from_, where))
```

How do you make sure that you are not giving users ability to execute arbitrary code. This framework admits all possible functions. Well, you can right a wrapper over it for security that expose a fixed list of function objects that are acceptable.

```
ALLOWED_FUNCS = [ operator.mul, operator.add, ...] # List of allowed funcs

def select_secure(keys=None, from_=None, where=None):
    if keys is not None and isinstance(keys, dict):
       for v, fun keys.values:
           assert fun in ALLOWED_FUNCS
    if where is not None:
       assert_composition_of_allowed_funcs(where, ALLOWED_FUNCS)
    return select(keys=keys, from_=from_, where=where)
```

How to write `assert_composition_of_allowed_funcs`.  It is very difficult to do that it in python but easy in lisp. Let us assume that where is a list of functions to be evaluated in a lips like format i.e. `where=(operator.add, (operator.getitem, row, v1), 2)` or `where=(operator.mul, (operator.add, (opreator.getitem, row, v2), 2), 3)`.

This makes it possible to write a `apply_lisp` function that makes sure that the where function is only made up of ALLOWED_FUNCS or constants like float, int, str.

```
def apply_lisp(where, rowsym, rowval, ALLOWED_FUNCS):
    assert where[0] in ALLOWED_FUNCS
    return apply(where[0],
          [ (apply_lisp(w, rowsym, rowval, ALLOWED_FUNCS)
            if isinstance(w, tuple)
            else rowval if w is rowsym
            else w if isinstance(w, (float, int, str))
            else None ) for w in where[1:] ])
```

Aside, you will also need to check for exact types, because you do not want your types to be overridden. So do not use `isinstance`, use `type in (float, int, str)`. Oh boy we have run into:

> Greenspun's Tenth Rule of Programming: any sufficiently complicated
>   C or Fortran program contains an ad hoc informally-specified
>   bug-ridden slow implementation of half of Common Lisp.