# Multiple matches of regular expressions with different strings

Tags: python, regex

It's quite difficult to describe (especially as a non-native speaker), but I'll do my best:

In my python program, I have a database of, let's say, news articles and one of the users wanting to be informed about a subset of them.
Every news object has multiple strings like *Author*, *Title* or *Text*.

I want to save the user's interests as an expression which allows me to match the different string attributes and combine those matches with logical operators like this (The syntax doesn't really matter):

```
attribute author matches pattern (\w*\sSmith) and attribute text doesn't
contain pattern (financ(e|ial))
```

Then, I have to iterate, for every user, over all articles and if the expression is valid, inform him/her.

My problem is that I don't really know what language to use. I'd like to avoid creating my own and writing my own parser with all the usual problems (security, escaping, etc.) because I'm sure this is a fairly common problem and there has to be a better solution than I'm able to create.

I've searched the web for some time now, but haven't found anything. Every help is very appreciated; thanks in advance!

**[Edit:]** Reformat pseudo-code as RabbidRabbit suggested.

Comment: By reformat as plain text, I meant in a code block as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting. Look at the edit history. I already edited it for you.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this problem. They range from a list of `(attribute, regexp)` tuples that you apply in a per-object basis to more complex things.

One option is to find some kind of declarative "language" with which you can specify simple queries such as the one you mention. This can be something that would be stored in a JSON or YAML structure, it all depends on how complex/extensible you want it to be.

If you want it to be really extensible, you may event want to have a DSL (domain-specific language):

http://www.slideshare.net/Siddhi/creating-domain-specific-languages-in-python

Here is a past StackOverflow post that may be helpful.

[Writing a Domain Specific Language for selecting rows from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140026/writing-a-domain-specific-language-for-selecting-rows-from-a-table)

The simplest solution I can see (to parse, generate and store) is a LISP-style prefix list of tuples, such as:

```
[('and', ('body', '.*to be or not.*'), ('author', (not, '.*shakespeare.*'))),
 ...]
```

If all you need is basic boolean operators and RegExs, that should be enough.

**[Edit]** Added example

Comment: Well, I fear that writing my own parser and especially inventing my own syntax for the DSL will result in a huge mess and leave me with more problems than before :S Concerning extensibility, I really don't need more than those attribute, regex pairs combined with And, Or and Not + Parentheses. Could you please elaborate on the *apply in a per-object basis* part? I'm not english and don't get what you mean, sorry :S

Comment: @camelNeck then keep it simple and use a list of tuples or something like that. Answer updated with example.

Comment: I've implemented your strategy and it works fine! On the other hand, the DSL method looks too interesting to leave it alone :) For saving, I still have to think of a neat way to extract the structure from text anyway, so I'll try creating my own DSL and using the tuples internally. Thanks for your help!